# File Explorer quick access missing folders

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

How do I reset quick access to the original way? This is how look like. Original:
[image] Mine [image]

Comment: right click > restore defaults?

Comment: I did, nothing changed

Comment: perhaps followed by taskmanager > explorer.exe > right click > restart?

Comment: Windows 10 or 11 ?

Comment: I have windows 10

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** You can clear Quick Access.   Restart after clearing and test.

Here is a screen shot of clearing Quick Access

[image: Clear Quick Access]

I have used this process successfully.

**(2)** If clearing Quick Access does not solve the issue, then you probably should do a Windows 10 Repair Install

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

**(3)** It is also quite possible that your Windows User Profile is damaged.  If so, a Keep Everything Repair will not work and the most practical way forward in this case is to back up and reinstall Windows 10 .

Comment: i did it, its always empty

Comment: You probably should do a Windows 10 Repair Install. Noted in my answer

Comment: It is also possible that your Windows User Profile is damaged leading to this issue. If so (and as I noted), back up and reinstall Windows is the fastest and most practical approach.